# Nobody likes me, yet I am never alone

Tags: riddle

Whether I am American or French is still unknown. I am notorious for my wanderings in Africa, anyway. I just go from one place to another, and stay there, sometimes unbeknownst and sometimes until they have enough of me. 
Nobody likes me, yet I am never alone!

Do you know who I am?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are

> [syphillis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_syphilis)

Because

> '''There are two primary hypotheses: one proposes that syphilis was carried to Europe **from the Americas** by the crew of Christopher Columbus, the other proposes that syphilis previously existed in Europe but went unrecognized.'''
>  ...'''the disease was known as **"French disease"**'''
>
>  Note: It has also been called "Italian disease", "Polish disease", "Spanish disease", "Christian disease", and "Western European disease".
>
>  "An estimated 492,000 infants in Sub-Saharan **Africa** die each year from congenital syphilis" - The Lancet 364 (Oct 2004)

Comment: Accepted; although there is a sharper match

Answer (score 1):

I think you're

> Disease.

My reason being.

> Nobody likes Disease, or (illness), yet no matter what you're always with someone... the host. If you stay wherever you go, that's due to disease spreading in one way or another, staying there from then on. Sometimes unbeknowst. Because some diseases aren't detected until there's a lot of it you the country.

Apologies, this was my first answer ever on a puzzle such as this, so my answer had skipped over some information. I understand now that it was the wrong answer, or more to the point, an answer that was correct, though not quite specific enough on which.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're

> Mullato, which is an individual who possesses French and African ancestry(While being an American)

"I just go from one place to another, and stay there,
sometimes unbeknownst and sometimes until they have enough of me"

> A person that possesses a bloodline of two races will come to identify himself in a category later in ones life. Until then, their mindstate of who they are on the outside constantly goes from *one place to another*, meaning they're switching their identity of ones self continuously. *Sometimes unbeknownst*, meaning that their subconscious mind has already decided for them with the idea of who they are. *And sometimes until they have enough of me.* Meaning that it's possible for one side of the family(although they share the same blood) can decided that the individual with two ethnicities isn't "one of them". Which forces the individual to identify with the race that didn't resent him *Nobody likes me, yet I'm never alone* Although it can be hard to be divided into two families that dislike eachother based on the differences that makeup who you are. That individual always has to remember that he is not the only one in his current position enduring his same battle

.

Comment: Hey, I can't make the edit but, usually in answers you 'hide' your answers and reasoning using >!. Interesting answer though!

Comment: Haha Thank you! I thought i'd go against the grain with this one lmao. It's poorly written and i think id love someone to make an edit right about now to fit that.